# why server-side datatables show all records in one page and search doesn't work?

Tags: java, jquery, mysql, datatables, playframework-2.6

I have been working with data-table . everything is working quite fine, the issues is that
- pagination not working perfectly, 
- searching not working
- all data showing only in one page

I used the below code for the initialization of the **datatable**-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').DataTable({

        "processing" : true,
        "serverSide" : true,
        "pageLength" : 5,
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
        "ajax" : {
            url: "/users",
            type:"GET",
            dataSrc : "data",
        },
        "columns":[
             {"data": "id"},
            {"data": "name"},
            {"data": "tweet"}
        ]
    });
```

});

and my **controller servie** (play framework)

```
 public Result ListAll(){
    List<User> users = User.find.all();
    System.out.println(toJson(users).toString());
    DataTableObject dataTableObject = new DataTableObject();
    dataTableObject.setData(users);

    String json = toJson(dataTableObject).toString();
    System.out.println("----> " + json );
    return ok(toJson(dataTableObject));

}
```

and **DataTableObject class**

```
public class DataTableObject {
    int draw = 1;
    int  recordsTotal= 26;

    int  recordsFiltered =26;

    List<User> data;

    public int getRecordsTotal() {
        return recordsTotal;
    }

    public void setDraw(int draw) {
        this.draw = draw;
    }

    public int getDraw() {
        return draw;
    }

    public void setRecordsTotal(int recordsTotal) {
        this.recordsTotal = recordsTotal;
    }

    public int getRecordsFiltered() {
        return recordsFiltered;
    }

    public void setRecordsFiltered(int recordsFiltered) {
        this.recordsFiltered = recordsFiltered;
    }


    public List<User> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<User> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

and this is a screenshot of my http://localhost:9000/

Answer (score 1):

When using `serverSide:true` Datatables does not handle searching, filtering, paging or ordering. You have to manipulate your query based on the [sent parameters](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side)  datatables is sending with the Get/Post request when you page, sort or search on your table.